# How to use percentage for font in different screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following DIVs:

```
<div class="tckLeftHolder">
    <div class="tckLeftContents">
        <span>URGENT CARE WAIT</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tckLeftContents
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0 0 0 10%;
    height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tckLeftHolder
{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 17px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #EA7C30;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(238,146,85,1);
}
```

Displays this in different screen size:

[image]

How can I make the font be responsive, so that the size increases/decreases based on the screen.

Update:

[image]

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 860px)
{
    .tckLeftContents
    {
        font-size: 1vmin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use viewport units, that vary based on the defined container's size (width and/or height)

```
{
    font-size: 1vmin;
}
```

Being the possible values:

- **vw** - relative to viewport's width
- **vh** - relative to viewport's height
- **vmin** - relative to viewport's width or height (whichever is the smaller)
- **vmax** - relative to viewport's width or height (whichever is the larger)

Check out the [**W3's docs on Viewport Relative Lengths**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths), that states:

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

Comment: Increase the value, it is a percentage... like `3vmin` or `10vmin`. Even decimal values `5.85vmin`

Comment: I checked in different screen size and they are all the same for 1VMIN :/ Is that normal?

Comment: Kind of... When it is veeery small you'll hardly notice the difference... See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vbaoq9gb/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `media-queries` like here:

```
@media (max-width: 699px){
  .tckLeftHolder
{
    font-size: 8px; //or how much pixels you want
}
}
```

Comment: I guess that is the only way... how about vertically center it even after font-size increase/decrease?

Comment: text-align:center normally does the job

Comment: Vertically :) What you wrote is horizontal