# Scale text to fill its container

Tags: css, html

I am making an `80x25` VGA text-mode simulator in JavaScript and am trying to get the terminal to resize with the window as opposed to a fixed-size terminal in the corner (like my previous attempt at this project). How do you scale text to fill its container in CSS?

I ask this because I am able to make the spans for each character ~4.16% width and 1.25% height so that the screen is `80x25`, but the font-size percents are relative to the current size of the font.

XY problem? Maybe. I'll edit it to be a better question if it is determined to be so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use percentage for font in different screen size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240138/how-to-use-percentage-for-font-in-different-screen-size)

Comment: Check my accepted answer at that question. Viewport Units

Answer (score 0):

You may find this javascript useful if you aren't to bothered about the method and would just be happy with a working solution

[FitText](http://fittextjs.com/)

Hope this helps ;)